# Getting Started with Dapper and SQL Server database

Tags: c#, html, sql, sql-server, dapper

I am working on a personal project to display information on a webpage. I haven't done SQL connections in over a year and this is also my first time using dapper so I am having trouble getting started. I have a table (`dbo.BallData`) stored in a database using SQL Server Management Studio:

```
+-------+-----------+---------------+--------------+-------------+-------------+--------------+---------+
| ID    | COMPANY   | NAME          | WEIGHT (lbs) | CORE        | COVERSTOCK  | SURFACE      | LAYOUT  |
| 1     | Hammer    | True Blood    | 15           | First Blood | Polyester   | 4000 Polish  | NULL    |
| 2     | Columbia  | Eruption Pro  | 15           | Resurgence  | CR300       | 1500 Polish  | NULL    |
+-------+-----------+---------------+--------------+-------------+-------------+--------------+---------+
```

I would like to display the information as follows. Currently the information is just typed out in HTML:

**Company:** Hammer 
**Name:** True Blood 
**Weight (lbs):** 15 
**Core:** First Blood 
**Coverstock:** Polyester 
**Surface:** 4000 Polish 
**Layout:**

I am working in C#, but cannot remember how to connect to a sql server database from visual studio. I am just hoping that someone can get started and then I can go from there. I have dapper included in my project. I have a file named BallData.cs where I am trying to connect to the database so that I can pull data out of it. Currently the file is just bare-boned because, like I said, I don't know where to begin.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace PracticeApp.App_Code.Entities
{
    public class BallData
    {

    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Whether it is pointing me to a tutorial or giving some examples to help me get going. Of course, I am not looking for the completed app. I am just looking for help on getting connected and applying dapper so that I can get in the information displayed. Thank you to anyone who is willing to assist me!

Comment: Connection strings are a good place to start: http://www.connectionstrings.com/

Comment: Thanks. ill check out that link!

Answer (score 3):

First you need an object model; for example:

```
public class Foo {
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public string Company {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    // ...
}
```

Then you need a connection:

```
using(var conn = OpenConnection()) {
    var items = conn.Query<Foo>("select * from YourTable");
}

DbConnection OpenConnection() {
    return new SqlConnection({some connection string});
}
```

But to do something *useful* needs a bit more context.

Rendering as html would be best done using a tool like razor:

```
@foreach(Foo row in Model.Items)
{
    <tr>
      <td>@row.Company</td>
      <td>@row.Name</td>
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: Ok, I have the object model. Now I am working on the connection. I will let you know if I get it to work.

Comment: @Jason9024 I can't write your app for you; once you can get the data, where you put it is up to you

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to use the IDE for your connection using a datasource [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s4yys16a(v=vs.90).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s4yys16a%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) also, I can give you an example of how to connect programmatically, but it's in VB and you can just translate that to c#.

```
Dim objConnection As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings.Item("Connection").ConnectionString)
Dim objSelectCommand As New SqlCommand("SQL statement if you desire it", objConnection)
Dim objDataReader As SqlDataReader = Nothing

objConnection.Open()
objDataReader = objSelectCommand.ExecuteReader
```

I hope this helps you out.